# Simulate a Click on an Image with usemap

Tags: c#, vb.net, webbrowser-control

I know how to simulate a `click` event on a button using webbrowser control. However, I am not able to simulate the `click` event on an image with usemap with `mouseup` and `mousedown` events associated.

how can I do it?

Bellow is the html associated to the image and to the usemap:

```
<img src="http://www.temp.com/zoom_off.gif" id="photo_zoom" style="width: 39px; height: 23px; border: 0" alt="" usemap="#btnZCMap">

 <area shape="rect" coords="2,2,19,25" href="#" onmouseover="doBtn('photo_zoom','in'); return false;" onmouseout="ZM=0; doBtn('photoe_zoom','off'); return false;" onmousedown="ZM=1; doZC(-1); return false;" onmouseup="ZM=0; return false;" onclick="return false;">
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to get the element, and then invoke the correct member, for example:

```
For Each elem As HtmlElement In webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img")
    If elem.GetAttribute("alt") = "MyImage" Then
        elem.InvokeMember("click")
    End If
Next
```

If this didn't work you could try the `RaiseEvent`:

```
WebBrowser1.document.GetElementById("ImgID").RaiseEvent("onclick")
```

Comment: If the image did not have "usemap" attribute, I could do what you suggest. unfortunately, I want to "click" in part of the the image (map), because each part of the image has a different event associated.